# chrome.proxy doesn't work for HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am trying to route all requests using:

```
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "https",
        host: "localhost"
      },
      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
  };
  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
      {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
      function() {});
```

This works wonderfully for all `http://` websites but not `https://`. It seems that Chrome doesn't even connect to the proxy in those cases but simply returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` (no packets in the VPN from chrome)

Answer (score 0):

https proxies differ from http proxies. It is HTTPS protocol, not HTTP.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS
As i understand you run proxy on local machine, so you need https proxy software.
Smth like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent
http:// and https:// means protocol. So is ftp, pop, smtp, ed2k, bitcoin... an so on.

Comment: Thank you for your output, the connection is established over HTTPS but Chrome seems to "skip" the proxy when I visit any `https://` website using the posted code. This results in `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `"https"` scheme instead use `"http"`
If proxy server protocol is `"https"` then `"http"` scheme will work like `"https"`
Google Chrome version 103.0.5060.114 64 bit